# Matplotlib for Python 3.6 64bit windows

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-wheel

I often found the file `matplotlib-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` for download. I also updated numpy to the latest release.

Opening the matplotlib-wheel using pip.exe I get the message: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dateutil`

Does anybody have an idea, how to run matplotlib with python 3.6 anyway?

I found this article:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8009/

But I still tried version 1.5.3 and it also lead to the same error message.

My problem: I always have to download the wheel-files before, as I always receive this message, using pip with only the package-name:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend you to install/update python-dateutil through `pip install -U python-dateutil`

I've successfully installed and I'm currently using this version of matplotlib with python 3.6 on a win64 installation.

Comment: In the end, I have still problems updating python-dateutil

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with `six` library. Try to install it separately